# AKS scale options

Tags: azure, scale, azure-aks

I have an AKS cluster with 5 nodes and autoscaling enabled. The CPU and memeory utilization is about 15% but the nodes are not scaling in, even the minimum nodes are set to 2.
I checked the AKS nodes (VMSS) scaling settings and found out the it is set to "Manual Scale" by default.

Could it be the reason of AKS not scaling in? Shall i create a customized autoscaling on VMSS level?
What is the best practise? Where shoud i define the autoscaling - In VMSS or AKS layer?
I am a bit confused.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Even though autoscaling is enabled for the Node pool in the AKS, the VMSS scaling to set to manual by default.

This is because Autoscale is not configured for the VMSS

You need to configure the autoscale for your VMSS

Go to your VMSS --> Under Settings, select Scaling --> set your scaling type to custom autoscale

[image]

Configure your Autoscale condition by adding a rule

Now, based on your autoscale condition, autoscaling of the VMSS will be done

Comment: It means that, AKS node autoscaling will not take any action until the VMSS scaling is configured? How they work in sync?
As far as i understand, Microsoft does not recommend customized VMSS scaling : "Don't manually enable or edit VMSS scalability settings in the Azure portal or using the Azure CLI. Instead, use the cluster autoscaler."